# can i get event callbacks to be executed in batches?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding about 40 callbacks to an 'input' event using Jquery I find that about 15 of these events can be executed smoothly, but that executing all 40 callbacks has noticeable lag.

Is there a way that I can get the callbacks to be executed in batches? order is not important.

My callbacks are added like this:

```
var easingTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1300 - 300 + 1)) + 300;
var searchable = (sName + sCode + hProp + com + om).toUpperCase();
$('#liveSearch').on('input', function(e) {
    var val = $('#liveSearch').val().toUpperCase();
    var showTemplate = (searchable.indexOf(val) >= 0) ? true : false;
    if (showTemplate) {
        template.show(easingTime, 'swing');
    } else {
        template.hide(easingTime, 'swing');
    };
});
```

Comment: The exact answer would depend on how your callbacks are setup. Show some code.

Comment: Add 1 callback and call your 40 functions.

Comment: ALso, I fail to see how adding 40 event handlers to one element (`#liveSearch`) would make any sense. I think something is missing from this question.

Comment: I do not know how useful it would be in your case, however, consider using `setTimeout`.

Comment: @Jamiec - this code is run in a foreach callback. so this code is scoped to each template

Comment: After https://stackoverflow.com/q/48154379/1427878 this is now the second time that you just talk about a larger number of callbacks/event handlers, without describing what you actually want to _achieve_ here. Please edit your question in that regard - then we can perhaps find a more suitable approach.

Comment: "this code is run in a foreach callback. so this code is scoped to each template" - that's nuts. Its the DOM/event handler piece thats slow. Attach one event handler and do the work inside it. Show us a [mcve] and we'll get you an answer if you struggle with the code.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should manage 1 callback and internally resolve your 40 cases... but it's better if you show your code.

Comment: Effects in JavaScript plays with the CSS and slowdown your page, try to use stop(true) to remove any queued animation, because the effect is running with any change applied to your input.